# Access component from custom validator in Angular2

Tags: forms, validation, angular, dependency-injection

I'm writing a **custom validator** for a **custom form component** in Angular2.
Right now, i can inject dependencies in my custom validator such as services.

But i need to have access from the validator to informations stored in the Component...

So i'm trying to inject the component in the Validator class, but this does not work..

I think i'm missing something with DI !

**Look at this plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/77muDxHCw7haGjTXWBcw?p=preview)**

When you open it, everything should work fine.
Uncomment everything in the validator constructor, like this:

```
constructor( private test: TestService, private component: CustomFormControlComponent ) {
  test.serviceMethod();
  component.componentMethod();
}
```

And check the log output to see that DI failed to resolve the second parameter ...

Any idea why ?

Thanks a lot !